# Why does my multi-IP per NIC setup in netplan disrupt my network

Tags: docker-compose, netplan

I recently connected my second NIC on my server (running Ubuntu server LTS 22.04) and changed `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` as described below to add multiple IPs to the second NIC (`eno1` has IP `10.0.30.21` assigned from DHCP reservation).

Afterwards, service A (in a docker container) could no longer by reached by service B (in a VM on the same machine) at service A's IP (`10.0.30.21`), despite the fact that (1) I could access them and the control them just fine using that IP, and (2) I used the

```
   ports:
      - "10.0.30.21:8080:8080"
      - "10.0.30.21:8443:8443"
      - "10.0.30.21:5911:5911"
```

syntax in my docker-compose file so they should just stay at 10.0.30.21:PORT.

Service A seemed to become discoverable by service B at an IP like `172.19.0.12`, which looks like a docker network IP.

What's more, service B (DHCP reservation: `10.0.30.61`) was also reachable at that internal IP through browser, but no longer worked when using the FQDN (I use nginx via the [linuxserver/swag](https://docs.linuxserver.io/general/swag) docker container).

I'm thinking I did something wrong with my netplan, as I'm far from an expert on this, I mostly just followed instructions, e.g., [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1119345/cant-add-second-ip-adress-via-netplan-on-ubuntu). So I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong here.

"old" netplan (works, but only one IP per NIC):

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
             - eno1
      parameters:
        stp: true
  vlans:
    vlan40:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 40
      link: eno2
```

that I switched to this (= problems, and lots of them) - none of the IPs conflict with anything in the DHCP server:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
    eno2:
      addresses:
        - 10.0.30.22/24
        - 10.0.30.23/24
        - 10.0.30.24/24
        - 10.0.30.25/24
  version: 2
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
             - eno1
      parameters:
        stp: true
  vlans:
    vlan40:
      accept-ra: no
      id: 40
      link: eno2
```